# JAXB treatment of xs:normalizedString

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

Suppose you have a complex type

```
<xs:complexType name="RepeatingNormalizedStringType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="repeatingNormalizedString" type="xs:normalizedString" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

JAXB maps the element `repeatingNormalizedString` to

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "repeatingNormalizedString", namespace = "urn:test", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected List<JAXBElement<String>> repeatingNormalizedString;
```

rather than

```
protected List<String> repeatingNormalizedString;
```

as you might expect.

This behaviour occurs with all subtypes of `normalizedString`. It also manifests when an element in a repeating group or sequence has type `normalizedString`, in these cases the group/sequence is collapsed to:

```
protected List<JAXBElement<?>> synthesisedGroupOrSequencePropertyName;
```

even when you would normally expect `List<Object>` or `List<NearestCommonSupertype>`.

I've read around the JAXB spec e.g. section 6.7, 6.12 but can't find any description of this situation.

My two questions:

1. Why is this behaviour occuring? My guess is it is to do with the fact that `normalizedString` and its subtypes must have a type adapter applied to them.
2. Are there any other simple types with which this behaviour will occur?

Cheers,

Matthew

Comment: Furthermore JAXB maps:

    <xs:complexType name="NormalizedStringComplexType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:normalizedString"/>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  
  To a generated Java class rather than java.lang.String.

Comment: I've subsequently bashed my head against this problem a bit more. I am now worried this may be a JAXB 2.0/XJC bug. See my question at http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/treatment-normalizedstring-jaxb-20-vs-21 for more details.